# Get response header OkHttp

Tags: java, retrofit, okhttp

I need to check response header of `HTTP request` using `OkHTTP` library. before loading data I need to check it's last update time. The problem in that that the response body is about `2 MB` so I need to get only `Last-Modified` header. Is it possible to load only response header without response body to increase the speed of the program`s RESTful actions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can send a HTTP [HEAD](http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/Request.Builder.html#head--) request which only retrieves the headers. You only need to check if your server application supports HEAD requests.

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can
>   be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the
>   request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is
>   often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility,
>   and recent modification.
>  (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Example for OkHttp:

```
String url = ...
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).head().build();
```

Comment: Could You write an example of how can I do that with OkHttp? I can't find in javadoc methods that operate it (((

Comment: @Near1999 I corrected the Javadoc link in my answer. Its now pointing to the `head()`method in `Request.Builder`. Does this help?

Comment: I know how to build request, I don't know how to build **HEAD request**, and the javadoc has no helped me ( I know how to add headers to the request and how to get them on response, but I don't know how to get only headers without downloading body from the server. If You know how, please, post a code example.

Comment: @Near1999 added an example

Answer (score 5):

The response body is streamed, so you can make the regular request, read the headers, and then decide whether or not to consume the body. If you don’t want the body, you can `close()` it without much waste.

There is a slight cost to the server to serve a response that might be abandoned. But the overall cost will be lower than making a `HEAD` and then a `GET` request unless you expect abandon a significant fraction (say > 90%) of requests.

Comment: So, when I call **response.body()** the body of the request only begins to download?

Comment: _Almost_. It'll download the first few KiB before that, but it won’t download too much until you call `response.body()`.